# Django REST Framework - create child of nested relationship

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm building an API with the Django Rest Framework for a site that allows users to create posts, and comment on those posts.  I'm able to create posts from the API fine, but when I try to create a comment I get the following error:

NOT NULL constraint failed: app_comment.post_id

my models:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name = 'posts')
    post_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    post_description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)

class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name = 'comments')
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name = 'comments')
    text = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
```

and my comment serializer:

```
class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='user.username')
    post = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='post.id')
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('id', 'text', 'user', 'post')
```

and my comment view:

```
class PostCommentList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,
                            IsOwnerOrReadOnly,)
    serializer_class = CommentSerializer
    def get_queryset(self):
        post = self.kwargs['post_pk']
        post = Post.objects.get(pk = post)
        return post.comments.all()
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        post = self.kwargs['post_pk']
        print("creating a comment from " + str(self.request.user) + " on post " + str(post) +" : "+ str(Post.objects.get(pk = post)))
        serializer.save(user = self.request.user)
        serializer.save(post = self.kwargs['post_pk'])
```

When attempting to create a comment on a post, I see the correct information being printed out (i.e. 'creating a comment from user on post 6 : Post object').

Why are my comments not being created with the correct post_id?

Comment: Why are you overloading `get_queryset` and `perform_create`? I guess it should work normally if you don't do it. Could you check it, please?

Comment: I'm overloading get_queryset so that the only the comments attached to a specific post will be returned, and I'm overloading perform_create so that I can get the post number form the url and the user from the request (similar to the example here: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/).

I'll try removing them, but I believe it will break other functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your perform_create function you are getting the primary key which is an integer, not a Post object. Also, you don't want to call save twice - it will result in saving two models (assuming it doesn't throw validation errors - which in this case it is).

A better way to do this might be:

```
post_pk = self.kwargs['post_pk']
post = Post.objects.get(pk = post_pk)
serializer.save(user=self.request.user, post=post)
```

Also you'll probably want to add the text content to the model you are saving as well. So perhaps, so you may need to add/change it to read:

```
text = self.kwargs['text']
serializer.save(user=self.request.user, post=post, text=text)
```

While I'm thinking of it - you may want to save a call to 'get' and avoid a trip to the database and specify the foreign key directly. You can do that using this syntax:

```
post_pk = self.kwargs['post_pk']
# Note - we won't call '.get' here
serializer.save(user=self.request.user, post_id=post_pk, text=text)
```

Comment: Didn't realize I could put multiple parameters in the save function, thanks!

I don't need to add the text to save though, I believe because it is handled by my serializer class.

Comment: I have a similar issue to this.Can you help look into this please?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62655168/not-null-constrained-error-on-field-handled-in-views-py

Answer (score 0):

Well, the most obvious error is that you are calling save() twice, first with a user and the with a post. And in the first call it tries to create a comment without a post and causes the database to give you the failed constraint error. Replace

```
serializer.save(user = self.request.user)
serializer.save(post = self.kwargs['post_pk'])
```

with

```
serializer.save(user=self.request.user,
                post=int(self.kwargs['post_pk']))
```

and you should be fine.

That said, you should probably remove the ReadOnlyFields and just add read_only_fields to the serializer meta

```
class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('id', 'text', 'user', 'post')
        read_only_fields = ('post', 'user')
```

Comment: This looks similar to the issue I'm having presently. Can you help look into it please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62655168/not-null-constrained-error-on-field-handled-in-views-py